# the type or namespace Xtralayout does not exist in the namespace Devexpress

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, devexpress

I am creating an USER INTERFACE in my programing class, and I am using Devexpress but it can not run because visual studio 2019 says:

```
the type or namespace Xtralayout does not exist in the namespace Devexpress
```

I am using C# and a plataform .NET

````
namespace Inventario_UI.Catalogos
{
    partial class FrmListarProveedorcs
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.layoutControl1 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControl();
            this.Root = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlGroup();
            this.formAssistant1 = new DevExpress.XtraBars.FormAssistant();
            this.labelControl1 = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl();
            this.layoutControlItem1 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem();
            this.emptySpaceItem1 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControl1)).BeginInit();
            this.layoutControl1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Root)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // layoutControl1
            // 
            this.layoutControl1.Controls.Add(this.labelControl1);
            this.layoutControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.layoutControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.layoutControl1.Name = "layoutControl1";
            this.layoutControl1.Root = this.Root;
            this.layoutControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.layoutControl1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.layoutControl1.Text = "layoutControl1";
            // 
            // Root
            // 
            this.Root.EnableIndentsWithoutBorders = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
            this.Root.GroupBordersVisible = false;
            this.Root.Items.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraLayout.BaseLayoutItem[] {
            this.layoutControlItem1,
            this.emptySpaceItem1});
            this.Root.Name = "Root";
            this.Root.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Root.TextVisible = false;
            // 
            // labelControl1
            // 
            this.labelControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.labelControl1.Name = "labelControl1";
            this.labelControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(63, 13);
            this.labelControl1.StyleController = this.layoutControl1;
            this.labelControl1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.labelControl1.Text = "labelControl1";
            // 
            // layoutControlItem1
            // 
            this.layoutControlItem1.Control = this.labelControl1;
            this.layoutControlItem1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.layoutControlItem1.Name = "layoutControlItem1";
            this.layoutControlItem1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(780, 17);
            this.layoutControlItem1.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            this.layoutControlItem1.TextVisible = false;
            // 
            // emptySpaceItem1
            // 
            this.emptySpaceItem1.AllowHotTrack = false;
            this.emptySpaceItem1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 17);
            this.emptySpaceItem1.Name = "emptySpaceItem1";
            this.emptySpaceItem1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(780, 413);
            this.emptySpaceItem1.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            // 
            // FrmListarProveedorcs
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.layoutControl1);
            this.Name = "FrmListarProveedorcs";
            this.Text = "FrmListarProveedorcs";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControl1)).EndInit();
            this.layoutControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Root)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControl layoutControl1;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlGroup Root;
        private DevExpress.XtraBars.FormAssistant formAssistant1;
        private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl labelControl1;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem layoutControlItem1;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem emptySpaceItem1;
    }
}
```
````

Comment: check if `DevExpress.XtraLayout.v19.2.dll` is referenced by your project?

Comment: --Thanks friend, Devexpress was not updated. That was why VS did not get the reference. Your answer helped me to find the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Devexpress was not updated. That was why VS did not get the reference.

In visual Studio

go to extensiones-devexpress-project convert--upgrade all